# MVC Html.ActionLink renders Area as QueryString instead of as part of the URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The following line in one project:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Today's Specials", "Specials", "Shop", new {area = "Books" } , null)
```

Correctly renders the following link URL:

http://example.com/Books/Shop/Specials

But in another visual studio application the exact same link renders the following **incorrect** link URL:

http://example.com/Shop/Specials?area=Books

Both apps use .net 4.5, however the second app where it **doesn't** work uses a slightly **newer** version of System.Web.MVC (5.2.30128.0 vs. 5.0.11001.0) and System.Web.Razor (3.0.30128.0 vs. 3.0.11001.0).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, you have it because in one of the projects you don't have call in Global.asax:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

It also may depend on your routes.